# What is the difference between working express vs next.js with strapi

Tags: node.js, express, next.js, strapi

I am new to nodejs development, the fist thing I started to learn is express but I was looking for CMS functionality so I found strapi.

Is strapi something that can be added to express or is it a stand alone app. I worked will php and MVCs.

My first project using node is to creating a website that I can change the contact (CMS), forms with verification and a simple blog with with tags.

what is found is next.js and strapi can work together

if this question was accepted then my question is not general
[What are the differences between Koa and Express 4.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64427106/what-is-the-difference-between-express-vs-strapi)

Comment: I like that the way strapi works to organize my database and relation but what I am stuck on express vs next.js as strapi works with both